# Javascript two dimensional array include

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS where I try to figure out wether a element of a 2D array is included in another 2D array. However, includes seems not to work, I get mismatch logged to the console for every index in the loop. How can I do this with a 2D array?

```
deleteLinks.on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var currentHTML = $('.product');
    var currentHTMLMap = $('.product').toArray().map(elm => [ $(elm).attr("data-id-product"), $(elm).attr("data-id-product-attribute") ]);
    var deleteIndices = [];
        $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {

             var newHTMLMap = $(data).find(".product").toArray().map(elm => [ $(elm).attr("data-id-product"), $(elm).attr("data-id-product-attribute") ]);
              for(i = 0; i  < currentHTMLMap.length; i++){
                  if (!(newHTMLMap.includes(currentHTMLMap[i]))) {
                  console.log("found mismatch for index " + i);
                  deleteIndices.push(i);
                  }
              }
                 for(i = 0; i < deleteIndices.length; i++) {
                currentHTML[deleteIndices[i]].remove();
}
          }
    });
});
```

I get the following data inside the variables:

```
currentHTMLMap: 6,0,2,9,1,1
currentHTMLMap[0]: 6,0
currentHTMLMap[1]: 2,9
currentHTMLMap[2]: 1,1

newHTMLMap: 2,9,1,1
newHTMLMap[0]: 2,9
newHTMLMap[1]: 1,1
```

Comment: please add the data in literal notation.

Comment: what do you mean? I posted everything like it was logged out to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and the elements with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var array = [[6, 0], [2, 9], [1, 1]],
    subset = [[2, 9], [1, 1], [1, 2], [4, 5]];

console.log(subset.map(a => array.findIndex(b => a.every((v, i) => v === b[i]))));
```

Comment: but I need the index of the mismatch, as in my example. Btw am I right that includes() does not work on 2D arrays?

Comment: it works with objects/arrays as well, but with the same object reference, not with just another array with same values inside.

Comment: So I could create another list with the indexOf(-1) and then I have the elements from the original arrays where a mismatch was found?

Comment: you could create another list with the found items. if you like to filter `subset`, you could just filter it.